# Relational query return null values

Tags: mysql

I have a question. In my database there are 2 tables. For example say:
Calendar table

- uid
- name

Signup table

- uid
- calendar_id
- user_id
- coming (-1 no, 0 undecided, 1 yes)
  0 = undecided but not record is also undecided

User table

- uid
- name

And i want to see what users are coming to a specific event. So i have the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM user u, signup s
WHERE u.uid = s.user_id
AND s.event = 1
```

But this shows me all the users who have actually created a record in the database. I also want to see the users who don't have a record in the signup table. How can i achieve this?

Kind regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the old implicit join syntax any more. Use explicit joins. In your case - a left join

```
SELECT *
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN signup s ON u.uid = s.user_id
                  AND s.event = 1
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you :)